# Huginn: Extract text from html tag using Website Agent css selector

Tags: html, ruby

I'm trying to understand how the web-scraping is done in Huginn but I cannot find proper documentation on the options available.

I'd like to extract the price of the Gold oz. from this website for example:
https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=XAU&To=USD

For which I use a Huginn Website Agent with this code:

```json
{
  "expected_update_period_in_days": "2",
  "url": "https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=XAU&To=USD",
  "type": "html",
  "mode": "on_change",
  "extract": {
    "price": {
      "css": ".converterresult-toAmount",
      "value": "."
    }
  }
}
```

I got the css selector using SelectorGadget and I've tried multiple values like: ./node(), string(.), normalize-space(.), . , //text() and others, but I cannot find the way to extract the content of the span html tag that contains that value. Here the code of that section of the web:

```
<span class="converterresult-toAmount">1,730.35</span>
```

And what I want to extract is: 1,730.35

Answer (score 0):

i got it working on another site.

i used "xpath" for it.
I used a different site because it wouldn't work on the one you posted.
But i hope this still helps someone.

```
    {
  "expected_update_period_in_days": "2",
  "url": "https://walletinvestor.com/converter/xau/usd/1",
  "type": "html",
  "mode": "on_change",
  "extract": {
    "gold_in_dollar_price": {
      "xpath": "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/h2/strong/span",
      "value": "string(.)"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here is how you get the XPath of any Element/Object on a website:
(i used Yandex Browser based on chrome for this)

1. Open the Developer Tools in the Browser (or right click and select "Inspect element code")
2. Select / Click with the Inspector on your Element/Object
   You should now see something like:

> `<span class="converterresult-toAmount">1,730.35</span>`

3. Right click on this and click: "copy" > "Copy XPath"

---

Im using Huginn since 2 Days so anyone feel free to tell me any faster way if there is any :)